# как я могу использовать PonyORM?

Tags: python, pyqt5, mvc, orm

Данные сохраняются в файле в json формате. Могу ли я как-нибудь использовать **PonyORM** для сохранения данных, либо применить её где-нибудь ещё?

```
import sys
import json
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


qt_creator_file = "mainwindow.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qt_creator_file)
tick = QtGui.QImage('tick.png')


class TodoModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, todos=None, **kwargs):
        super(TodoModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.todos = todos or []
        
    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            _, text = self.todos[index.row()]
            return text
        
        if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
            status, _ = self.todos[index.row()]
            if status:
                return tick

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self.todos)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.model = TodoModel()
        self.load()
        self.todoView.setModel(self.model)
        self.addButton.pressed.connect(self.add)
        self.deleteButton.pressed.connect(self.delete)
        self.completeButton.pressed.connect(self.complete)

    def add(self):

        text = self.todoEdit.text()
        if text:
            self.model.todos.append((False, text))
            self.model.layoutChanged.emit()
            self.todoEdit.setText("")
            self.save()
        
    def delete(self):
        indexes = self.todoView.selectedIndexes()
        if indexes:
            index = indexes[0]
            del self.model.todos[index.row()]
            self.model.layoutChanged.emit()
            self.todoView.clearSelection()
            self.save()
            
    def complete(self):
        indexes = self.todoView.selectedIndexes()
        if indexes:
            index = indexes[0]
            row = index.row()
            status, text = self.model.todos[row]
            self.model.todos[row] = (True, text)
            self.model.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            self.todoView.clearSelection()
            self.save()
    
    def load(self):
        try:
            with open('data.db', 'r') as f:
                self.model.todos = json.load(f)
        except Exception:
            pass

    def save(self):
        with open('data.db', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self.model.todos, f)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: https://coderlessons.com/articles/java/python-101-vvedenie-v-poni-orm

Comment: Можете. Никто не запрещает